# Laravel : size validation not working

Tags: laravel

I am using trying to validate mobile number length.

```
$this->validate(request(),[
     'mobile'=>'numeric|size:10|unique:client_details,contact',
      ]);
```

Still i am getting error: The mobile must be 10.
Is there any alternative method to validate.

Comment: try min and max

Comment: Validate it as string. Mobile numbers are not generally always numeric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documents says:

> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value. For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For an array, size corresponds to the count of the array. For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

So if you want to get mobile number then you should use string|size:10 and if you prefer to use numeric you should use max integer that you can get which is 9999999999.

Comment: btw i used this 
`$this->validate(request(),[
     'mobile'=>'numeric|digits:10|unique:client_details,contact',
      ]);`
replaced size with digits and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel validation rule regex.

```
'phone' => 'numeric|unique:client_details,contact|regex:/[0-9]{10}/'
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-regex)

But also do note that mobile numbers sometimes need to be stored as string for example 022-123456 etc. for that you'll need to modify your regex little.